# Canvas won't overlap in XAML

Tags: xaml, canvas, overlap

I have the follow XAML code which gives a students score for a course (these are the green, yellow and red bars, they are TextBlocks) the grey bars next to them are the standard deviation scores, they are Rectangles. The grey bars need to be underneath the colored bars.

I have tried to use ZIndex but this didn't change anything.
It does overlap with the horizontal lines with the numbers next to them, these are also Rectangles.

I have to use textblocks for the colored ones (it's an assignment from school).

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Ivory" FontSize="12" Background="Red" Height="45" Width="162" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0" Opacity="0.5" Canvas.Top="258" Canvas.Left="275">
    Boekhoudkundig inzicht
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15" Direction="60" ShadowDepth="3" />
    </TextBlock.Effect>
  </TextBlock>
  <Rectangle Height="3" Width="45" Fill="Black" Canvas.Top="284" Canvas.Left="275" />
  <Rectangle Height="80" Width="45" Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.5" Canvas.Top="229" Canvas.Left="275" />
```

The full XAML code can be found at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3K6yy2mv)

Comment: Sounds simple enough, but having trouble visualizing the result your after. Maybe an image of what it is now, and and an image of what it's supposed to be would help clarify your intent?

Comment: how it is supposed to be http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2i8gg36/8  , how i have it http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2n9aple/8

Comment: Oh.... easier than I thought.... Just take what you have there and embed it all in a single `Grid` so it sits on top of one another, though you will need to lose those Canvas.Left margins ya got on there. So just `<Grid>ALL YOUR STUFF</Grid>` ...easy peasy.

Comment: My teacher said that the bars have to be on the canvas

Comment: Well your teacher isn't teaching very good design principles if it's all hard coded margins and stuff, but that's another topic....anyway, just put that stuff in the Grid, and put the Grid on the Canvas with the margin stuff applied to it instead of the individual objects.